# jackson @JsonFormat unexpected timezone output

Tags: java, json, date, jackson

I have this POJO :

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Scheduling {

    @JsonProperty("created_at")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", timezone = "UTC")
    public Date creationDate;

}
```

Using java 8 and jackson 2.7.8, I serialize it through:

```
String s = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(scheduling);
System.out.println(s);
```

I expect an output like in the official documentation for SimpleDateFormat: `{"created_at":"2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-07:00"}` but I get a Z timezone instead: `{"created_at":"2017-03-31T15:42:44.923Z"}`. I tried X, XX and XXX, each one displays a Z timezone. `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` does however display a +0000 timezone, without the colon, as intended. Am I missing an option?

Comment: I understand your output, but what do you actually expect as an output? +0000 instead of Z?

Comment: I'd expect something like `2001-07-04T12:08:56.235+00:00`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a keen eye for reading that part of the docs :).

In short, 'Z' in the patterns represents a RFC822 time zone offset. It is always 'Sign TwoDigitHours Minutes'. However, X (or multiple Xs) represents ISO8601 designators and that can be any of the well known combinations, which include hours, minutes AND time zone letter symbols, including 'Z'(ulu). Actually, if a GMT+0 time is supplied, it will tend to serialize it as 'Z' instead of +00:00. I'm not aware that this can be changed. Also, be aware that formatters using 'Z' as the time zone pattern will **not** parse letter time zone designators.

More here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#rfc822timezone

However, I am not sure you should be bothered. As long as the date format against a standard, in your case ISO8601, any sane parser will be able to pick it up, in any language.

Comment: Thanks for those details, I had actually come to the same conclusion that Z can't  probably be replaced by +00:00. But as you stated, I guess it'll do.

Comment: Thank you for this I was starting to lose my mind!!!